# Send data to node server from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I have a sipmle Ruby on Rails app.

**`index.html.erb`**

```
<h3>Import</h3>
<%= form_tag import_zip_code_data_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

**`zip_code_data_controller.rb`**

```
def import
    uploaded_io = params[:file]
    begin
      uri = URI('http://localhost:4001/zip')
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
      req.body = { "uploaded_io" => uploaded_io}.to_json
      res = http.request(req)
      puts "response #{res.body}" // response Hey, it works!
      puts JSON.parse(res.body)
    rescue => e
      puts "failed #{e}" // failed 743: unexpected token at 'Hey, it works!'
    end
  end
end
```

Server side, I'm using a node to build out an API:

```
app.post('/zip', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.headers\n', req.headers) // I can see the headers I'm sending from the rails client
  console.log('req.body\n', req.body) // Undefined
  res.send("Hey, it works!")
})
```

I can't view the payload that I'm sending with the post request.  I can only view the headers (`req.headers`).

Is it possible to view the file that was uploaded from my Rails app inside my node server?

Comment: What kind of a file is this you are trying to send from controller ? Type application json might not let you do that. What packages are you using on node front to receive a file through post ?  Google around for an example of sending file attachments from ruby and also receiving them on node.

Comment: Trying to send a csv file (or the contents of the file).